# ROS Answers SE migration: ROS Thesis

Tags: ros, hardware

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am in my final semester of my masters program and I have decided to base my thesis on ROS. I would like to do something related to the benefits of using ROS or to enhance ROS itself in someway. Apart from those ideas I would appreciate any other ideas as topics for my thesis as long as they are related to ROS. I have a few other ideas as well, but I am also curious as to what the community might come up with.

I also thought about doing a demonstration of a live robot that makes use of ROS in an interesting and novel way. I have a few potential robot kits that I can do the demo with, but I am not sure if they can be integrated with ROS. And the ones that can be integrated, are out of my budget. Is there a cheap robotic kit that I can use with ROS for my thesis?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10149/ros-thesis/) by [kissandra79](https://answers.ros.org/users/648/kissandra79/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2011-06-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) on 2011-06-06**:
Which budget do you  have at your disposal (estimate is fine), and what do you think to achieve with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should check Tutlebot: http://www.willowgarage.com/turtlebot

Otherwise, almost any robot should be potentially controllable using ROS. You only need to develop a package that implements a ROS wrapper on top of whichever interface your robot uses.

---

Originally posted by [Miguel Prada](https://answers.ros.org/users/164/miguel-prada/) with karma: 1071 on 2011-06-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Miguel Prada](https://answers.ros.org/users/164/miguel-prada/) on 2011-06-06**:
Maybe some of the comments in this thread can help: http://answers.ros.org/question/40/which-robot-can-or-should-i-get-to-run-ros

**Comment by [Miguel Prada](https://answers.ros.org/users/164/miguel-prada/) on 2011-06-06**:
You should be able to devise some bridge from ROS to the pi bot using its arduino compatibility and some wireless link, I guess. I do think it's much more limited, though. Have you considered a naked iRobot Create? It sure has more potential for upgrades, if you later feel like it.

**Comment by [kissandra79](https://answers.ros.org/users/648/kissandra79/) on 2011-06-06**:
I checked it. But it is way too expensive for what I want to do with it. Even the one without the "create" and the laptop is expensive. At the moment I am thinking about the pi bot from pololu robotics but I'm not sure if I can integrate ROS with it.